# How to update a row in a different sql table with the help of Triggers

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am currently working on a Java Swing application. The application allows the users to perform different types of transactions. I have created some tables in **MS SQL** to store the user data. The following is the problem that i am facing at the moment.

I have a table called "UList" which contains all the info about the user. This particular table also contains a column called "Balance" which will hold the balance of a user. There's another table called "Deposits", which will hold the deposit amount.

The tables:

**Ulist**

```
╔══════╦═════════╗
║ id   ║ balance ║
╠══════╬═════════╣
║    1 ║    6000 ║
║    2 ║    4000 ║
╚══════╩═════════╝
```

**Deposits**

```
╔══════╦══════╗
║ amt  ║   id ║
╠══════╬══════╣
║ 1000 ║    2 ║
║ 1000 ║    1 ║
║  500 ║    1 ║
║  500 ║    1 ║
╚══════╩══════╝
```

Now whenever a user will perform a transaction, the amt will be inserted in the Deposit table and will be updated/added to the balance with the help of foreign key id. I have tried the following trigger, but it doesn't work as intended.

```
create trigger d_trigger
ON Deposits
AFTER INSERT
AS
UPDATE u set u.balance=u.balance+d.amt from UList u INNER JOIN deposits d on u.id=d.id INNER JOIN inserted i on i.id=d.id
```

This trigger works when i am inserting the same numbers. If i insert 500, then it will successfully add 500 in the balance, but the moment i use another number like 1000, it will update incorrect values. I have several triggers like this on different tables which performs similar operations like withdrawal, transfer etc.

Your help with this issue will be really appreciated !

Note: In case you were wondering if it is the Java Code that is creating this issue. I have tried this both in the application and in the MS SQL Server.

Comment: This is because your join condition finds multiple entry for same `id` already in the `deposits` table. You need to capture the `amount` and `id` as given in `insert` statement for `deposit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The INNER JOIN on Deposits table in your TRIGGER is not needed. This should work:

```
alter trigger d_trigger
ON Deposits
AFTER INSERT
AS
    UPDATE u 
    set u.balance=u.balance+i.amt 
    from UList u 
    INNER JOIN inserted i on i.u_Id=u.u_Id
```

Comment: This worked like a charm ! Thank you very much for taking your valuable time to answer my question :) . I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but the idea is to set the value with a simple update statement. There  is no doubt  this is the reason for your errors.

```
create trigger d_trigger
ON Deposits
AFTER INSERT
AS
UPDATE UList set balance = balance + :new.amt
WHERE id = :new.id;
```